# Train loss and accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

In theory, is it possible that the loss on the train set will increase together with the train set accuracy? (in the normal case the train set loss should go down)
And vice versa, can the train loss decrease along with the accuracy?

Note: This is obviously different than the classic underfit / overfit cases which are easier to grasp.

Comment: Certainly it is possible that loss decreases and accuracy stays the same (loss defined in terms of probabilities vs discrete accuracy).

Comment: But why? Can you provide an example please?

Comment: E.g. target is [0, 1] and predicted probabilities are [0.1, 0.1] in first case and [0.45, 0.45] in second case. Say that you use >0.5 decision rule for classification, so the classifications won't change (and so accuracy), but loss possibly will (say log-loss or squared loss).

Comment: @Tim I've copied your comments to an answer. If you would like to write your own answer, please let me know so that I can delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, @Tim writes:

> Certainly it is possible that loss decreases and accuracy stays the same (loss defined in terms of probabilities vs discrete accuracy). E.g. target is [0, 1] and predicted probabilities are [0.1, 0.1] in first case and [0.45, 0.45] in second case. Say that you use >0.5 decision rule for classification, so the classifications won't change (and so accuracy), but loss possibly will (say log-loss or squared loss).

---

I've copied this comment as a *community wiki* answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

Please review

- [Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question/5320#5320)
- [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)